# Where does Visual Studio 2015 install .NET Framework?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having some issues compiling a large Web Forms application after upgrading from Visual Studio 2012 to 2015.

It looks like Visual Studio 2012 used version *4.0.30319* of the framework, and Visual Studio installed version *4.6.0081*. However, the directory structure doesn't seem to show this. Does anyone know where Visual Studio 2015 installs the .NET libraries?

[image]

The directory structure looks the same under *Framework64* as well.

Comment: How lame is it to downvote something without saying why? You haven't indicated what you think is wrong and you haven't helped to improve anything. AFAIC, anyone willing to downvote something should be willing to stand behind the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Framework 4.5 and 4.6 are a in-place update of the .NET 4.0 Framework. The assemblies are replaced with the new version inside de v4.0.30319 folder. It doesn't create an new folder structure.

See more: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx